# Transform View Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, data-modeling

I want to create a VIEW TABLE in my database based on a source table in **SSMS (SQL Server)**.
But it's super hard to get the wanted view table format.

Here I present an example of the source table.

| Country | sales_date | sales_code | type_item | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Algeria | 06/01/2024 | ACTUAL | Hat | 200 |
| Algeria | 06/01/2024 | ACTUAL | Shirt | 145 |
| Algeria | 06/01/2024 | ACTUAL | Pant | 150 |
| Algeria | 06/01/2024 | TARGET | Hat | 90 |
| Algeria | 06/01/2024 | TARGET | Shirt | 500 |
| Algeria | 06/01/2024 | TARGET | Pant | 100 |

Here is how I want my table to be shown:

| Country | sales_date | hat_sales_ACTUAL | hat_sales_TARGET | shirt_sales_ACTUAL | shirt_sales_TARGET | pant_sales_ACTUAL | pant_sales_TARGET |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Algeria | 06/01/2024 | 200 | 90 | 145 | 500 | 150 | 100 |

I did try to use joins but it seems to hard to get it right.

Comment: What is a `VIEW TABLE`? A `VIEW` and `TABLE` are different object types.

Comment: Also SSMS is just an IDE-like application that is used with several products such as (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure Synapse. SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question here. What product are you actually using for your data engine? Tagging [[tag:SSMS]] for your data engine is like tagging [[tag:visual-studio]] for your programming language; it doesn't actually really tell us anything.

Comment: What you want, however, is known as pivoting; there are literally [10,000's of posts](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pivot+sql+server+site%3Astackoverflow.com) on the subject; what about the wealth of information out there already didn't you understand? What were your attempt(s)? Why didn't they work?

Comment: @ThomA, a view is one kind of table, and base table is another kind. (I know, most people mean base tables only when talking about tables.)

Comment: @ThomA - Yes there are 10,000 pivot posts out there, but the ones that address the specific multi-column axis that the OP is looking for seem to be few and far between, I scanned the first 25 results from your search and found none. If I added multi-column to the mix, most of the results covered the "multi-axis cases" (like SumA, SumB, AvgA, AvgB) instead of the desired "multi-column axis case". I gave up searching through the noise and just answered the question. I expect similar cases are out there, I just didn't seem to have the right search keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are many examples of using PIVOT out there, but most do not show how to use a pivot axis that includes multiple columns like `sales_code, type_item`, and the answer is not obvious (unless you *already know the answer*).

Since PIVOT does not allow multiple column referenced in the `FOR` clause, you have to calculate a combined column value ahead of time.  This can be done by wrapping up a `CONCAT()` calculation is a `CROSS APPLY`.

The result would be something like:

```
-- Using a compound pivot axis PIVOT
SELECT PVT.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        Country, sales_date, sales,
        CONCAT(type_item, '_sales_', sales_code) AS Combined
    FROM Data
) D
PIVOT (
    SUM(sales)
    FOR Combined IN (
        hat_sales_ACTUAL, hat_sales_TARGET,
        shirt_sales_ACTUAL, shirt_sales_TARGET,
        pant_sales_ACTUAL, pant_sales_TARGET
   )
) PVT
```

Results:

| Country | sales_date | hat_sales_ACTUAL | hat_sales_TARGET | shirt_sales_ACTUAL | shirt_sales_TARGET | pant_sales_ACTUAL | pant_sales_TARGET |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Algeria | 2024-06-01 | 200 | 90 | 145 | 500 | 150 | 100 |

You can also use a `GROUP BY` combined with *conditional aggregation*.

If you do not know the columns ahead of time, you can use *dynamic SQL* to generate the the pivot `IN (...)` list and/or the final select column list, while omitting the original columns from the intermediate results.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ucl_xBuW) that includes the above as well as equivalent *conditional aggregation* and *dynamic SQL* alternatives.